# Use YQL to POST data to an URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, yql

**The current situation**:
The community I'm coding for has several sub communities with their own subdomains. Usually you could configure your webserver to allow requests between these subdomains. The community provider seems unable to provide this.

**The current solution**
To avoid CORS errors, we now using YQL for GET requests. This is approved by the community provider who have to review every script submitted by coders like me. This works already fine.

**The current problem**
I only figured out how to do GET requests using YQL. But is it possible to also POST data to another subdomain using YQL? And if it is, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

check out the documentation on how to make a POST-request:

```
var content = { "employee": { "name": "John", "id": 21 }};
var ret = request.contentType('application/json').post(content).response;
```

Source: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_execute.html#post-method

Comment: Thanks for this! I read the example but I can't see where `y` is initialized. Does that only work with an yahoo account?

Comment: @shaedrich the `y` object is already initialized when your code runs, you don't need to do anything. Also, you don't need an Yahoo account to use YQL.

Comment: The question might be stupid but where is it initialized. Do I have to load a yql library? Before I just used the API directly.

Comment: Again, please read the documentation: 
https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_execute.html#yglobal


`The y global object contains methods that provide basic YQL functionality within JavaScript. It also allows you to include YQL Open Data Tables and JavaScript from remote sources.`

Comment: That is not an answer. I know _what it is_, but not what I have to do that it is injected in `window` scope.

Comment: Oh, my assumption was that you were using custom table definitions, not javascript in browser. You will probably need to create a custom table xml with some javascript in it (that has the y-object). Hope this helps: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/dev-external_tables.html